# Porque en java tengo un character 13 antes del 10 al pasar un string a bytes[] en telnet?

Tags: java, socket, telnet

Hola me estoy volviendo loco y espero me puedan ayudar, necesito hacer un telnet y enviar la palabra "hello", pero antes debo incluir carácter 10 al inicio y al final el caracter 13.
El arreglo debería quedar así [10,104,101,108,108,111,13] y por alguna razón del lado del servidor lo estoy recibiendo así "data":[13,10,104,101,108,108,111,13]
Me podrían por favor indicar porque se agrega un 13 al iniciar el arreglo antes del carácter 10 y como lo quito?

He probado con un equipo micro y al enviar los datos al servidor lo recibe correctamente, por tanto el lado del servidor esta descartado puesto que esta funcionando correctamente en la recepcion de datos.

Este es mi código:

```
public class MainCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        TelnetClient client = new TelnetClient();
        String host = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 3021;
        client.connect(host, port);
        OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);

        String bodyCode = (char) 10 + "hello" + (char) 13;
        outputStream.write(bodyCode.getBytes());
        pw.flush();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        client.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: 10 es un salto de linea, 13 es un retorno de carro.. algunos SO no usan los dos para hacer una linea nueva, otro si. mira [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792168/73749), creo que podes investigar por ese lado porque alguien lo esta agregando...

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda, mi problema es que el protocolo de comunicación que utiliza el servidor existente debe enviar el char 10 al inicio y el char 13 al final. Lo raro es que tengo estructurado de esa manera y al enviarlo en el servidor me aparece así "data":[13,10,104,101,108,108,111,13]  ocupando el primer carácter un 13 y después el 10.
Debo enviar como primer byte el carácter 10 quedando de la siguiente forma [10,104,101,108,108,111,13], cabe indicar que la palabra "hello" que he puesto es solo referencial, en realidad aquí va la trama a enviar. Cual es la diferencia si uso write?